# Trying to fetch data from firebase in a table reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, map-function

I am trying to create a table looking for data from firebase, however the table is always giving error.
I put the whole function in a script to validate if any error in the component call, but always lists the same error: TypeError: **custos**.map is not a function
Does anyone know what can it be?
I already tested it and the variable **custos** can return the object, but I can't use it in the map function

```
function MeusCustos(){
    

    const [custos, setCustos] = useState([]);
    const [pesquisa, setPesquisa] = useState('');
    const usuarioEmail = useSelector(state => state.usuarioEmail);
    let listaCustos = [];

    useEffect( () => {
                firebase.firestore().collection('custos').get().then(async(resultado) => {
                    resultado.docs.forEach(doc => {
                            listaCustos.push({
                                id: doc.id,
                                ...doc.data()
                            });
                        }); 
                    setCustos(JSON.stringify(listaCustos));
                }); 
    }, []);  
    
    return(
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    
    <div className="row p-3">
    <div className="container">
            <h1>Simple Inventory Table</h1>
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Titulo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
                    <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                    <th scope="col">Data</th>
                    <th scope="col">Comprovante</th>
                    <th scope="col">UsuarioEmail</th>
                    <th scope="col">Visualizações</th>
                    <th scope="col">Publico</th>
                    <th scope="col">Criação</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {custos.map( item =>
                            <tr >
                                <th scope ="row"></th>
                                <td>{item.titulo}</td>
                                <td>{item.descricao}</td>
                                <td>{item.quantidade}</td>
                                <td>{item.valor}</td>
                                <td>{item.data}</td>
                                <td>{item.comprovante}</td>
                                <td>{item.usuarioemail}</td>
                                <td>{item.visualizacoes}</td>
                                <td>{item.publico}</td>
                                <td>{item.criacao}</td>
                            </tr> 
                     )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
    </>)
}


export default MeusCustos;
```

Comment: Don't stringify it. `setCustos(listaCustos);`

Comment: Also, put your `listaCustos` variable inside your useEffect hook

Comment: I tried to put this string in to try to escape from an error. When I do this configuration the error returns: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `useEffect` hook. Do not stringfy the array because it will become a string and the map function works on arrays, change `setCustos(JSON.stringify(listaCustos));`  so that your useEffect will look as follows:

```
useEffect( () => {
            firebase.firestore().collection('custos').get().then(async(resultado) => {
                    resultado.docs.forEach(doc => {
                            listaCustos.push({
                                id: doc.id,
                                ...doc.data()
                            });
                        }); 
                    setCustos(listaCustos);
                }); 
    }, []);
```

Comment: I tried to put this string in to try to escape from an error. When I do this configuration the error returns:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: comment the whole tbody, and write a console.log(custos) i want to see what kind of data are you getting. this error rises when yoi try to render an object or an array on the DOM

Comment: I found the problem, one of the values ​​had been written with sysdate, which brought data of seconds and nanoseconds breaking the date component

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, one of the values ​​had been written with sysdate, which brought data of seconds and nanoseconds breaking the date component
Tks 4 help guys